# пакетное переименование файлов с использованием Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Всем доброго временени суток!
В датафрейме (db_name_file) pandas, в столбце name_file_izm содержатся измененные имена файлов. Как их подставлять, чтобы переименовать все текущие, расположенные в директории dir? Пробовал такой код:

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    for row in db_name_file.itertuples():
        os.rename(file, row.name_file_izm)
```

Выдает ошибку, что "FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Невозможно создать файл, так как он уже существует..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если там соответствие один-к-одному, т.е. каждому файлу в каталоге соответствует одна запись в датафрейме и исходных названий файлов в датафрейме нет, то воспользуйтесь функцией `zip` для параллельного перебора коллекций:

```
for file,name_file_izm in zip(os.listdir(dir),db_name_file.name_file_izm.values):
    os.rename(file, name_file_izm)
```

Но лучше бы в датафрейме были и исходные названия файлов, тогда нужно просто попарно взять старые и новые имена файлов, а не полагаться на то, что у них будет правильное соответствие файлам в каталоге.

Comment: Большущее Вам спасибо, все работает ))